# Use of a dictionary + Bitarray

Tags: python-2.7

I need to know if a bitarray is already in a dictionary but I do not why my code do not work, any idea?

```
    dic={}
    bb=bitarray()
    bb.append(False)

    temp=bitarray()
    temp.append(False)
    dic[bb]=""

    if temp in dic:
        print("hello")
```

Comment: Did you find the answer below useful?

Comment: It works but it does not useful to my purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one. Dict's keys should be hashable. That said, let's take a look at the hashes generated for both bitarrays.

```
>>> bb
bitarray('0')
>>> temp
bitarray('0')
>>> hash(bb)
1871851
>>> hash(temp)
1871843
```

Therefore, when you attempt to do `if temp in dic:`, hash of temp is not found in dic. Therefore you don't get the desired result. I don't know why hash of bb and temp are different.

You could do this instead:

```
>>> dic[bb.tostring()] = 'test'
>>> if temp.tostring() in dic:
...     print 'hello'
...
hello
```

You could even use `bb.tobytes()` as the dict's key if you so desire. In that case, use `temp.tobytes()` for comparison.